# Parse/Decode response (Json format?) - PHP Curl

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, zoho

I am using PHP Curl to push html form data to a CRM (Zoho), where a record is created.

Response after creating the record (echo $response;):

*Record(s) added successfully*3442526000000497019*2018-09-04 11:32:312018-09-04 11:32:31*

I want to parse/decode this response ($response), to extract the record-Id (*3442526000000497019*).

In thre CRM API SDK, it says something about responses being in json format.

Therefore, I tried to decode the response with json_decode fucntion:

```
var_dump(json_decode($responser));
var_dump(json_decode($responser, true));
```

However, this returns a NULL (NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.) and not an array.

I would appreciate any tip, hint, fingerpoint to a good direction. Do I have to decode it in some other way?

The following extract of my script shows how the form data is inserted (as XML data to the CRM via php Curl):

```
<?php

$xml =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <Leads>
        <row no=\"1\">
            <FL val=\"Uhrzeit\">".$uhrzeit."</FL>       
            <FL val=\"Datum\">".$datum."</FL>
            <FL val=\"First Name\">'Mad'</FL>
            <FL val=\"Last Name\">'Dog'</FL>
            <FL val=\"Phone\">".$phone."</FL>
            <FL val=\"Email\">".$email."</FL>
            <FL val=\"Zip Code\">".$postcode."</FL>
            <FL val=\"fuerwen\">".$fuerwen."</FL>
            <FL val=\"pflegegrad\">".$pflegegrad."</FL>
            <FL val=\"mobilitaet\">".$mobilitaet."</FL>
            <FL val=\"sprache\">".$sprache."</FL>
            <FL val=\"betreuungsbeginn\">".$zeitpunkt."</FL>
        </row>
    </Leads>";
$auth="fewfwefwe";
    $url ="https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords";
    $query="authtoken=".$auth."&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&xmlData=".$xml;
    $ch = curl_init();
    /* set url to send post request */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    /* allow redirects */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    /* return a response into a variable */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    /* times out after 30s */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    /* set POST method */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    /* add POST fields parameters */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.

    //Execute cUrl session
    $responser = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $responser;

    var_dump(json_decode($responser));
    var_dump(json_decode($responser, true));
```

Kind regards
Leonore

Comment: this doesn't look like a json at all. Not even slightly close to a json format

Comment: From what I can see on their documentation they are expecting requests and responses to be json format, not sure where you've got the xml info from, at least on this page https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/

Comment: @lelio Since it points away from Json, does this means that it points to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM API SDK is implemented to deal with ZOHO CRM API Version 2 and the code you referenced is calling API Version 1.

You are posting to the XML API so, you should be expecting to receive XML response.

If you want to have a json response consider changing the XML part to JSON in the API URL like this: [https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/insertRecords](http://#) and it should be accepting the exactly same parameters as the XML API.

Here is a sample response:

```
{"response":{"result":{"recorddetail":{"FL":[{"val":"Id","content":"3442526888888888888"},{"val":"Created Time","content":"2018-09-11 14:21:31"},{"val":"Modified Time","content":"2018-09-11 14:21:31"},{"val":"Created By","content":"Jon Deo"},{"val":"Modified By","content":"Jon Deo"}]},"message":"Record(s) added successfully"},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Leads/insertRecords"}}
```

Please, consider removing the authtoken from your question as it is public now!

Comment: Thank you, I changed the response output to JSON and was able to parse it. I also managed to use substr() to retrieve the ID from the XML response. The fingerpoint to the authcode was also great. I'll consider exchanging it.